# Make vim open files as nomodifiable, under certain conditions

Tags: vim

How can I make open files as `readonly` and `nomodifiable`, if they're in a certain folder hierarchy, but do NOT contain a certain extension?

For example, if I open files on /server/(production|uat)/* I want to be prompted whether to edit the file, or just view it.  An exception might be needed as well--such as if the file contains the prefix `temp`.

Comment: You could replace your vim executable (at 'which vim') with a bash script that executes vim -R -M instead of vim if your conditions are met

Answer (score 3):

Put this into your .vimrc file:

```
autocmd BufReadPre,BufNewFile /Taboo/Dir/*  setlocal readonly nomodifiable
autocmd! BufReadPre,BufNewFile /Taboo/Dir/*/temp*.txt   setlocal noreadonly modifiable
```